# JQM changes vertical position

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with JQMobile. I have two divs that I have to have equal height so I have used display: table on a surrounding div and display: table-cell around my content.
However the problem is that while it works with plain HTML/CSS it gets messed up when I use JQM.

The basic code structure is

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">    
   <div style="width: 49%; display: table-cell">
      My content 1
   </div>
   <div style="width: 49%; display: table-cell">
      My content 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/liftarn/rt4nY/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the simple (but not very obvious solution) was to add a simple vertical-align:top as

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">    
   <div style="width: 49%; display: table-cell; vertical-align:top;">
      My content 1
   </div>
   <div style="width: 49%; display: table-cell">
      My content 2
   </div>
</div>
```